# Getting GPS coordinates perpendicular and parallel to AB?

Tags: google-maps, gps, geometry, google-maps-api, mathematics

[image]

I already posted a question [at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251745/finding-closest-90-degree-angle-spot/27266884?noredirect=1#comment43980058_27266884)

I got the solution from @Fang but the problem is that the coordinates I need to use are GPS coordinates and apparently GPS needs a different formula than cartesian.

I am working with Google Maps APIv3 polygons and having coordinates of AB (by drawing them with the polygon tool) I click on position C which I need to be moved to D which is perpendicular to AB and CD is parallel to AB

Having

```
A = 50.88269282423443,6.0036662220954895
B = 50.882753744583226,6.003803014755249
C = 50.88252571592428, 6.003832183778286

- D is perpendicular to AB
- CD is parallel to AB
```

What would be the formula to get D?

Comment: Would you be open to using a spatial database?  E.g. PostGIS or Oracle Spatial?

Comment: Not really, I am already using MySQL for the application and I dont want to add another database just for one function.

Comment: But I presume you can use the Google Maps Javascript API (v3)? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: Yes in fact I am already using API v3. And to be more exact, I don't know if you are familiar with Google Mapmaker. But in there when you use the "Add building" function and hold shift it snaps to a right angle. That's what I am going for.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mapmaker, but I might have a solution. Let me post it in the answers

Answer (score 1):

You have a few of useful functions in the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Reference under the [google.maps.geometry.spherical namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical), namely

- computeDistanceBetween
- computeHeading
- computeOffset

It's not quite possible to complete what you need with just those, but you could try using something from the [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) library to fill the gap.

For example, you could use [closestPoint](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/symbols/jsts.geom.LineSegment.html#closestPoint) method from your [line segment](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/symbols/jsts.geom.LineSegment.html) **AB** to get the point **E**, then get the heading (**h**) and distance between **E** and **C** (**d**), using computeHeading and computeDistanceBetweem, respectively, from the Google Maps API.  Now that you have the heading and distance, you can put **B** **d** and **h** to get your unknown point **D**

I've not had a chance to test this, but in theory it should work.

Comment: I'm experimenting with the library seems nice but so far it just keeps returning me undefined when I do for example: `console.log(jsts.geom.Coordinate(a.x, a.y));`

Comment: Yes, I found it a little awkward to get going.  I posted an example that used the DistanceToPoint method a while ago http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124926/whats-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-point-is-within-a-certain-distance-of-a-ge/125008#125008